# In binary search, how does computer choose mid point and when there is only two elements left

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

I've read some stackoverflow questions and other blogs about this matter.

Most of them explain to choose mid point by using:

```
1. low + (high - low)/2
2. (low + high)/2, round down to integer.
```

from [Deciding mid in binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803216/deciding-mid-in-binary-search) and https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/binary-search/a/binary-search

None of them quite make sense.

say I have a list in the form

```
lst = [2, 5, 8, 12, 16, 23, 38, 56, 72, 91]
```

using 1. midpoint = 46.5 and by using 2. midpoint = 50.5, rounded down to 50.

both midpoint isn't even in my list.

Furthermore when there are only 2 element, which one does it choose as a midpoint?

Comment: Binary search does not use the values of the elements. It uses the indices of the elements. In a list of ten elements, numbered from 0 to 9, the midpoint is around 4.5. Since that is not an integer element index, either 4 or 5 is used. When there are only two elements left, either one may be used as the midpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `low` and the `high` variables do not refer to the elements of the list or the array. They refer to the indices of the list or array. So the middle element will not be given by: `low + (high - low)/2` or `(low + high)/2` (round down to an integer) but rather by `lst[low + (high - low)/2]` or `lst[(low + high)/2]`

Comment: wait in my case lst[(low + high)/2] = lst[4.5], no?

Comment: In that case it will be rounded down to 4 (like you mentioned in the question for the second case)

Answer (score 2):

Binary search low/high refers to ndexes rather than array values.
So in your case mid **index** is (0+9)/2=4.

In case of length 2 you'll get mid index 0, right part will have one element, left is empty (or contains the only 0-th element, if mid is not treated separately).

Comment: oh why did I think it would be a element... Should I close this question?

Comment: It think no - somebody might face the same mistake.

Comment: This is a legitimate question and highlights a confusion faced by most people while learning about binary search. Even i encountered the same confusion. I think this question needs to stay (unless it hasn't been asked already)

Comment: Most of blog, stack overflow never mentioned it being an index (ones I've read). Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

1. `low` and `high` refer to the indexes of the list not the values of them
2. if there are two elements it would take the `low` and the `high` which will be 0 and 1 and then do `low + (high - low)/2` which would equal to `0 + (1 - 0)/2` which gives us `0.5` depending on your algorithm you can round up or round down, since you have chosen rounding down we have a value of `0` which will be the index of the middle point that will be chosen